# Can't connect to Samba (SMB) server Debian 11 XFCE

Tags: debian, samba, xfce

Can't connect to Samba server with Debian 11 and XFCE.

Scenario: Samba server has been setup on Truenas box.

Cannot connect to it using the path/url entry box in Thunar (file mananger.)

See this video for setup details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-5jbDTCsOE&t=573s

Answer (score 2):

To fix:

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

Test:

```
sudo smbclient //[IP]/share_name -U user
```

You should be able to login. Type `quit` to quit.

Now install `sudo apt install gvfs-backends`

This enables thunar to understand urls like: `smb://[IP]/samba_share_name`.

Enter the correct URL and a window should pop up prompting for a username and password.

Helpful article:

https://vitux.com/samba-debian-11/

My appologies for the very minimal question and answer - the essential info is here.

Comment: If you still have problems also try installing `cifs-utils` and `samba` packages